# Using Pexpect for communication between multiple programs via I/O

Tags: python, performance, io

I have a Python script that runs three compiled programs and makes them communicate via standard I/O. This is my first time using `pexpect`. My program runs very slowly. Is there anything that I can do to speed up the program? If not, I can try to do it with C/C++ pipe/fork.

```
import pexpect
import os

Checker = pexpect.spawn("./checker") # a turn based game
Player = [0,1]
Player[1] = pexpect.spawn("./player1") # same game with computer player
Player[0] = pexpect.spawn("./player2") # same game with computer player

# tell each player wether it is 1st or 2nd player
Player[1].sendline("1") # 
Player[1].expect("\n")  # delete input from before
Player[0].sendline("2")
Player[0].expect("\n")  # delete input from before

player = 1
while True:

    Player[player].expect("\n") # wait for current player's move(a line)
    move = Player[player].before.strip() # read current player's move
    print move

    if not Checker.isalive(): # this does not run in usual
        print "endgame checker died"
        break
    Checker.sendline(move) 
    Checker.expect("\n") # delete input from before
    Checker.expect("\n") # wait checker's response
    check = Checker.before.strip() # read the response
    if check != "": # checker will send an empty line if move is valid and game didn't end
        print "endgame   ", check # otherwise response is other player's number
        Player[0].kill(0) # kill all
        Player[1].kill(0)
        Checker.kill(0)
        break

    player = (player+1) %2 # change current player
    if not Player[player].isalive(): # this does not run in usual
        print "endgame" + player + "died"
        break

    Player[player].sendline(move) 
    Player[player].expect("\n")  # delete input from before
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `checker` and `player`s?

Answer (score 1):

here are a few ways to cleanup the code and make it more readable. This does not really go over functionality too much as I am not super familiar with `pexpect` or your other program you are trying to interface with. There are probably some optimizations to do the `While` loop in your program especially around the end where you are changing the `player` you are looping on but since I am unfamiliar I will leave that alone.

Without seeing the code or having a better understanding of how the checker/player works, this will be the best I can give for now.

- Unused imports aren't a terrible thing, but aren't really a good thing either, best to remove them.
- It doesn't seem like any naming convention is really being strictly followed. For example you have `Checker = pexpect.spawn("./checker")` but then later are doing `check = Checker.before.strip()`. It is best to follow PEP8 and stick with the snakecase naming convention. So it would be `checker = pexpect.spawn("./checker")`
- Similarly named variables can be confusing. You have `Player` and `player` but they are different things. Best to be more specific, `player_list` and `current_player` would be better.
- Use list literals instead of creating a list with aribitrary values then indexing in. You could rewrite

  ```
  Player = [0,1]
  Player[1] = pexpect.spawn("./player1")
  Player[0] = pexpect.spawn("./player2")
  ```

  as

  ```
  Player = [pexpect.spawn("./player2"),pexpect.spawn("./player1")]
  ```

  but that looks a little backwards, so I am gonna change all the indexing so player 1 is in index 0.

  ```
  player_list = [pexpect.spawn("./player1"), pexpect.spawn("./player2")]
  ```
- Use string interpolation

  ```
  print "endgame   ", check
  ```

  Would become

  ```
  print "endgame {}".format(check)
  ```

  and

  ```
  print "endgame" + player + "died"
  ```

  would become

  ```
  print "endgame {} died".format(player)
  ```
- Use the natural feel of booleans instead of `check != ""` where you should have done `if check`. Python will check for `None` and `""` for you.

Here is my version of the script that should function the same.

```
import pexpect

checker = pexpect.spawn("./checker")
player_list = [pexpect.spawn("./player1"), pexpect.spawn("./player2")]

player_list[0].sendline("1")
player_list[0].expect("\n")  # delete input from before
player_list[1].sendline("2")
player_list[1].expect("\n")  # delete input from before

current_player_idx = 0
while True:
    player = player_list[current_player_idx]
    player.expect("\n")
    move = player.before.strip()
    print move

    if not checker.isalive():
        print "endgame checker died"
        break
    checker.sendline(move)
    checker.expect("\n") # delete input from before
    checker.expect("\n")
    check = checker.before.strip()
    if check:
        # Really have no idea what you are trying to do in here, so I am leaving it alone. 
        print "endgame {}".format(check)
        player_list[1].kill(0) 
        player_list[1].kill(0)
        checker.kill(0)
        break

    # If I understand correctly, you are trying to see if the OTHER player is still alive.
    current_player_idx = (current_player_idx + 1) % 2
    if not player_list[current_player_idx].isalive():
        print "endgame {} died".format(current_player_idx)
        player_list[current_player_idx].sendline(move)
        player_list[current_player_idx].expect("\n")  # delete input from before
        break
```

Comment: There was not any bugs in program flow. Everything worked as I expected. I will change variable names and print formatted strings as you said.

Comment: Why even put that code I'm there then? It is possible it was just an indentation error. However putting a break before statements like that means those statements will never ever be executed.

Comment: Lines after break are not in the if block. I am going to include some comments in the code so that you can understand what it does.

Comment: I haven't changed the code.